# Error trying to import a module on expo bunddle: Unable to resolve "../shared/baseUrl" from "components/MenuComponent.js"

Tags: react-native, expo

I have been trying to run react-native app on expo on my android phone. I haven't been able because I am getting an error *Unable to resolve "../shared/baseUrl" from "components/MenuComponent.js"* on expo.

This is the folder tree of my project where you can see baseUrl and MenuComponent.js (The other js modules on components import baseUrl.js with error.):

[image]

The following is the imports section of the components/MenuComponent.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { Tile } from 'react-native-elements';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { baseUrl } from '../shared/baseUrl';
```

The following is the content of shared/baseUrls.js

```js
export const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/';
```

This is my package.json:

```js
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.0.0-beta8",
    "react-navigation": "2.0.1",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "redux": "4.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I am using those packages versions because they are the suggested on the course I am taking.

To solve the issue, I have tried

- yarn cache clean
- expo r -c
- Clear data/cache of expo on my cellphone.

Answer (score 1):

> The following is the content of shared/baseUrls.js

Are you absolutely sure the paths are correct?
What happens if you move the file in the same folder temporarily and include it from there?
`import { baseUrl } from './baseUrl';`

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested. There was leading space on the name of the file that I couldn't seet. Thanks!